# Doing a zsh 'if' where the pattern is stored in a variable

Tags: zsh

Zsh:

I have variables NAME and PATTERN and want to know, whether the string stored in NAME matches the glob-pattern stored in the variable PATTERN.

For example:

```
NAME=foobar
PATTERN='*ob*'
```

should give a match.

I can not do

```
[[ $NAME == $PATTERN ]] && ...
```

because the parameter expansion for PATTERN occurs too late. I **can** do one of

```
[[ $NAME == ${=PATTERN} ]] && ...
[[ $NAME == $~PATTERN ]] && ...
```

because both forms force $PATTERN to be expanded earlier.

Question: Which of the two forms is better? Is there a danger (a type of PATTERN) which will break the code? Is there maybe a better way to write this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `$~PATTERN` for two reasons:

1. As per the [*zsh* manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) is exactly the intended purpose of `${~spec}`:

   > **`${~spec}`**
   >   Turn on the `GLOB_SUBST` option for the evaluation of `spec`; if the `~` is doubled, turn it off. When this option is set, the string resulting from the expansion will be interpreted as a pattern anywhere that is possible, such as in filename expansion and filename generation and pattern-matching contexts like the right hand side of the `=` and `!=` operators in conditions.
2. `$=PATTERN` does not actually seem to work for your example. If I run the following on my machine (zsh-5.3.1):

   ```
   NAME=foobar
   PATTERN='*ob*'
   [[ $NAME == ${=PATTERN} ]] && echo '= does the trick'
   [[ $NAME == ${~PATTERN} ]] && echo '~ does the trick'
   ```

   I only get the following output:

   ```
   ~ does the trick
   ```

---

As to possible dangers: Barring any bugs in *zsh* itself, there should be no pattern that actually breaks your code, as in doing something other than pattern matching. The worst that should happen is that the pattern is incorrect/malformed so that it does not actually match its intended targets.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out with your zsh. While `=` happens to wrok on my old 5.1.1, it is good to know that this is not portable, and I will stick to `~`.